# GridView Groups should not start in a new column

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I've created a new GridView that groups the item by key.

```
<GridView
    Style="{StaticResource DefaultGridViewStyle}"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource TimeGroupCollectionViewSource}}"
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TransactionDataTemplate}" 
    MaxHeight="{Binding MaximumContentHeight}">
    <GridView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <ItemsWrapGrid Orientation="Vertical" GroupHeaderPlacement="Left"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemsPanel>
    <GridView.GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border Background="{ThemeResource B2}" Height="40" VerticalAlignment="Top" Tapped="Border_Tapped">
                        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource GroupTextBlockStyle}" Height="40" VerticalAlignment="Top" Text="{Binding Key}" />
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
            <GroupStyle.Panel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <VariableSizedWrapGrid Orientation="Vertical"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </GroupStyle.Panel>
        </GroupStyle>
    </GridView.GroupStyle>
</GridView>

<Page.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Name="TimeGroupCollectionViewSource" IsSourceGrouped="True" Source="{Binding TransactionList}" ItemsPath="Data"/>
</Page.Resources>
```

That works fine. By default every group starts in a new column.
[image: New column for every group]

What I want is something like this:
[image: No new column]

How can I achieve that? Do I miss some properties?

Answer (score 1):

If you want your grid to scroll vertically - you should try changing its `ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode` and `ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode` or use a `ListView` with custom `ItemsPanel`.

Comment: Only changing the scrollmodes didn't work. If I write a custom ItemsPanel what would that mean? Would you try to override the ArrangeOverride function to arrange the items? How would one know whether the item is a header or not?

Comment: Sorry, by custom I didn't mean you writing a custom one, but just using different than default.